# Install shows error in console: INSTALL FAILED CONFLICTING PROVIDER

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am experimenting with the NotesList sample program in the Android SDK. I've made a slight variation in the program, but when I install my edited version I keep getting the message INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER in the console when I try to install it when the original notes program is already on the device. What do I need to change in the Provider to make it a unique database? It works fine if I uninstall the original notes program and then install my edited version.

Answer (score 268, accepted):

The authority, as listed in `android:authorities` must be unique. Quoting [the documentation for this attribute](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html#auth):

> To avoid conflicts, authority names should use a Java-style naming convention (such as com.example.provider.cartoonprovider). Typically, it's the name of the ContentProvider subclass that implements the provider

Comment: @ CommonsWare I have used `android:authorities` attribute in my `AndroidManifest` `provider` tag. I have used that project as my android library project using this library project I have developed    few projects. how to solve the `install_failed_conflicting_provider` issue if we used common library project.

Comment: @jamal: If you are using Gradle for Android, such as from Android Studio, the manifest merging options will allow you to tailor the authority string. Otherwise, remove the `<provider>` from the library's manifest and define it at the application level with a unique authority string.

Comment: @ CommonsWare sir actually i am new to android studio can you please guide me how to merge (application level with a unique authority string)

Comment: @jamal: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-Placeholder-support -- if you have further questions, and you cannot find answers via a search, please ask a new Stack Overflow question.

Comment: I asked my friend to post a question here the link is below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26398255/how-to-merge-two-modules-in-android-studio

Comment: if you use library in two project with the same provider name it could cause this error

Comment: If you have multiple apps using a library project, and the library project uses Google Maps, you should see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34865104/1103584

Comment: I have no such thing like `android:authorities` or `<provider>` in my library manifest and getting this error.

Comment: @lef: Presumably it is coming from a `<provider>` in a library that you are using.

Comment: @CommonsWare correct, after all I eventually found different small lib with the `<provider>` tag in its manifest

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/users/1256914/jose-l-ugia's answer below for how to fix it

Comment: @ericf.: That only fixes certain scenarios, such as having a `debug` and a `release` build installed in the same device at the same time. It is not some universal fix.

Comment: content authority should be unique in provider. if you use same content authority in two project then it may be an issue. same problem i have faced.

Answer (score 205):

If you have different flavors and you want to avoid collisions in the authority name you can add an `applicationIdSuffix` to build types and use the resulting `applicationId` in your manifest, like this:

```
<...
 android:authorities="${applicationId}.contentprovider"/>
```

Comment: You can define your own `applicationId` on each product flavor definition. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#product-flavors

Comment: I think if you do this it will fix the differing product flavors as you have to create differing `applicationId` for each flavor anyway.  If you had different buildTypes you want `applicationId` to differ between those as well, and that's what the `applicationIdSuffix` property will do.

Comment: Thanks, using a hardcoded android:authorities in fileprovider is exactly my problem!

Comment: Great answer! Before adding these and run, clean old version of your applications.

Comment: I like this answer . . . . when you change package name, its authority for content provider changes with it dynamically. Thanks!

Answer (score 43):

This can also happen when you have an older version of your app installed and made changes to the (support) library or the manifest file. Deleting the old applications from your device (`Settings --> Application --> <your application> --> Uninstall`) will solve the issue then.

Comment: Same here. I was using genymotion virtual devices and had to remove the previously installed application.

Answer (score 32):

If you are using the Facebook SDK then the issue might be in the "authorities" value you provide for the Facebook provider.

REPLACE -

```
<provider
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:exported="true" />
```

WITH ->

```
<provider
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider[YOUR_APP_ID]"
        android:exported="true" />
```

You might need to change the `defaultConfig.ApplicationId` also as suggested in other answers.

Comment: upvoted, I suggest to use this: android:authorities="${applicationId}.com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"

Comment: i am working on app flavouring and stil facing the same issue first falvour apk intall successfuly but when i change to build variant for second got this error `Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER`
Code is: `<provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.com.freshdesk.helpdesk.provider" > `

Answer (score 31):

If you are using Google Maps + Google Play Services inside a library project (especially if you recently migrated from Eclipse to Android Studio), you can encounter this error when you try to run an app that uses your library, while a different app that uses the same library is already installed on your device.

**Fix:**
make sure that defaultConfig.applicationId is defined in android section of the `build.gradle` file for each project using your library

```
android {
    defaultConfig.applicationId = "com.company.appname"
}
```

I would recommend using the package name of the specific app.  With this fix, the provider names will no longer conflict, and your app will run as expected.

**Symptoms**

1.) Your users are seeing the dreaded "-505" install error when installing your app from the Play Store.

2.) You will see this error message when you try to install a second app that uses your library via Android Studio [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER]:

[image: Conflicting Provider]

In your console, you will see a message like this:

```
Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.company.appname-1
com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerException: 
Can't install because provider name 
com.google.android.gms.measurement.google_measurement_service 
(in package com.company.appname) is already used by
com.company.otherInstalledAppName
```

**The fix is to make sure that defaultConfig.applicationId is defined in android section of the `build.gradle` file for each project using your library**

```
android {
    defaultConfig.applicationId = "com.company.appname"
}
```

More reading can be found here in the original bug report: [Issue 784:  Multiple apps using same authority provider name](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=784)

Comment: I encountered this error after "simply" moving my projects from Eclipse to Android Studio and this tip solved the issue. Thanks

Comment: @PhilippeGirolami "simply" for sure.  It took us about a month to fully transition a very large project from Eclipse to Studio, and now we're penalized with 4+ minute build time, compared to 10-15 seconds in Eclipse.

Comment: @PhilippeGirolami android studio 2.0 is being built specifically to address the slowness - they're on beta 5.  However, use beta studio software at your own risk, sometimes it works great, sometimes it's horrible and will ruin your night.

Answer (score 17):

The same error may occur after renaming packages. Check the value in string.xml for `android:authorities` from AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<provider
        android:authorities="@string/content_authority"
        android:name=".data.Provider"
        ... />
```

In string.xml the value should be the same as your package name, declared in manifest.

```
<string name="content_authority">com.whatever.android.sunshine.app</string>
```

Comment: This is also a good solution but takes time+space to create new string in values for each provider in application.

Answer (score 9):

Stating the obvious, but also make sure you have not silently messed up the reference to the `applicationId` in  `android:authorities`.

In my case I made a typo and omitted the damn dollar sign :

```
android:authorities="{applicationId}.myprovider"
```

instead of :

```
android:authorities="${applicationId}.myprovider"
```

That did not cause any immediate error (since it is a valid authority name). But a couple days later, when I tried to install different variants of an application, it was a real pain to understand what was wrong, as the error message does not give much info about what is wrong with the content providers.

Another way to troubleshoot this is to compare your merged manifests, looking for identical authorities.

Answer (score 8):

The Authority + Provider name that you have declared in the manifest probably

Answer (score 8):

Basically this happened with me, when i tried to change the package name of the app.

So, in emulator, same app was installed before. When i tried to install app after changing package name, it said, authority already used by older application in device.

Simply after uninstalling the application, it solved my problem.

Also, Authority name should always be : `your.package.name.UNIQUENAME`;

example :

```
  <provider
        android:name="com.aviary.android.feather.cds.AviaryCdsProvider"
        android:authorities="your.package.name.AviaryCdsProvider"
       />
```

Comment: I added '           tools:replace="android:authorities"' to the provider.

Answer (score 8):

I have tried many solution but could not find solution... but this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25876527/1994950) helped me... I want to give detail about issue...

I was running Instrumented test cases so my app was not visible in launcher... but it was installed and thus using **Same Content Provider**. So, I should uninstall it somehow. So `Settings -> Application Manager -> All Downloaded Apps -> uninstall all apps from your current development package`

Now, try to run... This will work...

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem when I used one library in several applications. It was necessary just update your AndroidManifest.xml with this exact provider declaration below.

```
<manifest ...>
    <application ...>
        <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.here.this.library.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" tools:replace="android:authorities">
        </provider>
    </application>  
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 7):

I thought uninstalling the app by dragging its icon to "Uninstall" would solve the problem, but it did not.

Here is what solved the problem:

1. Go to Settings
2. Choose Apps
3. Find your app (yes I was surprised to still find it here!) and press it
4. In the top-right, press the 3 dots
5. Select "**Uninstall for all users**"

Try again, it should work now.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Facebook inside app check for provider tag inside `AndroidManifest` file and check your `project Id` is correct for `android:authorities`

```
<provider android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider112623702612345" android:exported="true" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Encountered this issue.

**Resolved it** by:

1 - open AndroidManifest.xml

2 - ctrl+f find "provider"

3 - find provider and update your root directory name there.

run project. hopefully issue will be fixed!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the emulator, you may try the following. The below worked for me.
Go to Tools --> AVD Manager --> (Pick Your emulator) --> Wipe Data.
The error went away.

Answer (score 2):

install using adb with command `./adb install -r abc.apk` will solve the problem (it will overwrite even when the device has higher app version)

Answer (score 2):

i had this problem :

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER
```

but it was not from provider of manifest
the below library in my app has conflict with other app and the others can not be install:

```
implementation 'com.iceteck.silicompressorr:silicompressor:2.2.1'
```

Comment: Facing the same issue when i added productFlavors

Answer (score 2):

I´ve got this error, when implementing an library with following AndroidmManifest.xml

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="library.path.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

I solved this when i put following Code in Project AndroidManifest.xml (app/src/main):

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        tools:replace="android:authorities">
    </provider>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah! I have the same problem as you。As you said,you use "variation". keep the "authorities" unique, you can write as this

```
android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
```

if you have a lib use in an app more than one,The same reason as above.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Xamarin and you get this error (probably because of Firebase.Crashlytics):

```
INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER
Package couldn't be installed in [...]
Can't install because provider name dollar_openBracket_applicationId_closeBracket (in package [...]]) is already used by [...]
```

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/issues/444), you need to update Xamarin.Build.Download:

1. Update the Xamarin.Build.Download Nuget Package to **0.4.12-preview3**

   - On Mac, you may need to check *Show pre-release packages* in the *Add Packages* window
2. Close Visual Studio
3. Delete all cached locations of NuGet Packages:

   - On Windows, open Visual Studio but not the solution:

     - Tools -> Option -> Nuget Package Manager -> General -> Clear All Nuget Cache(s)
   - On Mac, wipe the following folders:

     - `~/.local/share/NuGet`
     - `~/.nuget/packages`
     - `packages` folder in solution
4. Delete bin/obj folders in solution
5. Load the Solution
6. Restore Nuget Packages for the Solution (should run automatically)
7. Rebuild

Answer (score 1):

You can uninstall package name "com.example" from the device in which you run the app after than you run the app . This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

It helped me: Go AndroidManifest and paste or replace with this code

```
<provider
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.here.this.library.provider"
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        tools:replace="android:authorities" >

    </provider>
```

Answer (score 1):

**if your are using provider check and do it by following method**

```
        <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="androidx.multidex.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_path" />
    </provider>
```

**or use it**

```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.contentprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_path" />
    </provider>
```

**also if the applciation already exits in your mobile uninstall and then check**

Answer (score 0):

In my android device I had **different flavors of the same app** install. This gives me error **INSTALL FAILED CONFLICTING PROVIDER**. 
so I uninstall my all flavors of the same app. 
and tried

`adb install -r /Users/demo-debug-92acfc5.apk`

It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
        need to use android:name="androidx.core.content.contentprovider 
        or android:name="androidx.core.content.provider insteadof 
        android:name="androidx.core.content.fileprovider

        <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.contentprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Run the app on a physical device instead of the emulator. I encountered this issue and my app didnt have a content provider defined.

**Solution 2**

In the other instance, i had an instrumented test app installed matching the same applicationId.

To fix the issue i had to run  `./gradlew uA` - uA short for `uninstallAll` task.

You can alternatively use the Gradle panel and choose navigate to **app\install\uninstallAll** task

If you using an emulator, you can wipe out the data

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using Audience Network Content Provider you need to add this code in your app AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<provider
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider165632208074623"
        android:exported="true" />
```

**Your Facebook app id ---> 165632208074623**

Answer (score 0):

If you **only** need to use facebook for sign in to your app here is a tip:
(this fix worked in cordova project)
Step 1 and 2 must be completed to fix the problem.

1.
locate the file: platform/android/android.json
inside that file:
remove this code:

```
,{"xml": "<provider android:authorities=\"com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider<FACEBOOK_APP_ID>\" android:exported=\"true\" android:name=\"com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider\" />","count": 1
}
```

2. 

Then locate file: platforms/android/app/src/main/androidManifest.xml

remove this code:

```
        <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider<FACEBOOK_APP_ID>" android:exported="true" android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" />
```

Now the application can run fine..
Im sorry if this answer is not relevant for the OP, but it may help many others that have this problem. I could not find this exact answer anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried many solutions but couldn't find a solution**:
I changed this in AndroidManifest

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.com.shareFile"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
  </provider>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Make the authorities changes as said by @Jose L Ugia.

(You can find the provider in the manifest(merge manifest))

Mostly it will be connected to an SDK that you implemented, So remove the SDK implementation line and sync the Gradle, and then again add the implement line and sync the Gradle.

The implementation line:
`implementation files(<your SDK>)`

Provider code: (you have to scroll down in merge-manifest to find it )

Answer (score 0):

In my case different version of the App was already available on the device and that's why this issue was showing.

I just removed the previous application from the device.

Answer (score -2):

Check your **android:authorities** attribute under **<provider** tag

---

Check if your **package** name is correct or not