# Google play services dependency in a lib second install raise a conflicting provider exception

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services, android-contentprovider

I have implemented a library project which has **GMS play-services dependency**, and I use GCM, Google Cloud Messaging to receive notifications.

This library is a part of another android project which I can override properties, add custom code and then build android applications.

Everything is fine as far as I install one app built with a specific packageName, but if I change the packageName, rebuild and install the second app on the same device, **I got the error INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER** during the installation execution.

Removing GMS play-services dependency resolve the installation issue.

My question is how should I handle that ?

Can I specify the authorities for providers coming from GMS libraries ? Make something uniq for the built apk ?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, when I write changing the packageName, I mean in the AndroidManifest xml file

Comment: Oh, it's not clear. The library has a specific package name and I have an android project repository which includes this library and which I can override properties. I will rectify that in the top description.

Comment: You might use the package name that has conflict, eg you cannot use the `com.google.*` `android:authorities` must be unique. For more info please refer to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267785/install-shows-error-in-console-install-failed-conflicting-provider).

Comment: Related: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189079