# INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER with no contentProvider

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

Hi a get **INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER** and after trying of uninstall app I get failure (see below)

```
Installing cz.evolta.winwinjob
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/cz.evolta.winwinjob"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/cz.evolta.winwinjob
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER]


DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm uninstall cz.evolta.winwinjob
Unknown failure (Failure)
```

I read a lot about **android:authorities** and a**ndroid:exported** but nothing change. And beside that I dont have any **ContentProvider** in my app (mean in manifest).

But I use GCM to send push, Facebook SDK, Linkedin - is possible that error occurs cause of them?

And this error happens only on olny Nexus (4.3 - API 18) with a lot of apps (**is there any way to find where the collision exactly is** ?), but in Motorola Moto G (5.1 - 21), LG (6.0) and emulator (4.3 - api 18) it is OK.

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267785/install-shows-error-in-console-install-failed-conflicting-provider

Comment: @United121 did you find any solution? I ran into the name problem after updating android studio to 2.0 preview

Comment: @m.zander not yet, but I am using AS 1.5 so I think that problem isnt in new version

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem and the solution may also solve yours.
When you use exeternal libraries which provide providers, for some reason the authority is not set correctly anymore.

I solved the problem by setting the applicationId within the build.gradle file

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.myproject'
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try it. Unfortunately I dont have access to that mobile now but as soon as possible I will test it. Thanks in advance