# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE] followed by DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR

Tags: android, nexus-5

When im trying to run app on nexus5 device, android studio open error window that says "**installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER**" and than im asked if i want to uninstall existing application even if it doesnt exist on the device. 
also, the run window shows "**Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER]**"

when click ok i get on the run window :

**"DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm uninstall com.app.app
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR"**

thank you for your help!

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267785/install-shows-error-in-console-install-failed-conflicting-provider)

Comment: Please provide some code...

Comment: Are you using Marshmallow (Android 6.0+)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I noticed that when using Marshmallow (Android 6.0+) there is a problem with the new "com.google.android.gms" play services version 8.3.0 .
I would recommend using the 8.1.0 version - that solved the problem in my case.

for example:

```
dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
}
```

Need to be changed to:

```
dependencies {
            compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
            compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
    }
```

In the build.gradle file

Answer (score 2):

It may be installed with different signature.
You need to uninstall previous app.

You can check in **Settings>>Apps**

Comment: as i mentioned - this happens even when the app isnt installed on the device. tnx anyway!

Comment: please check once that app is uninstalled for all user

Comment: You can check it in settings

Comment: i truly did :( it isnt there

Answer (score 1):

**UNINSTALL** your app manually from device or run below command in `adb` command line

```
adb uninstall com.app.app
```

And try again to run your app.See [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12405/uninstall-system-app-failed-using-adb-shell-pm-uninstall) get more idea.

Answer (score 0):

For someone facing this issue on MI /  Xiaomi Phones, the solution is as follows:

Step 1: Check if installation from unknown sources is enabled:

```
Go to Settings-> Additional settings-> Privacy-> Unknown sources
```

Step 2: Goto `"Developer options"`, then enable "Verify apps over USB" in Debugging section.

Step 3: In the `"Developer options"` itself, enable `"Install via USB"` option.

If above all the options are in place and if you are still not able to install the app:

Step 4:  `Settings --> Additional settings --> Developer options --> Turn Off MIUI optimization` Disable this option, a dialog will pop-up to restart the device and apply changes.

Answer (score 0):

May be MI users are facing these problems
Just go to **Settings -> Mi Account**
Create a **Mi Account**.
Then go to **Developers options -> Install via USB** (Tick it or enable it)
there you go. Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Go to edit-configurations and uncheck allow parallel run

that did the trick for me, none of the other solutions I found worked