# android - DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR Error while Installing

Tags: android

i know this question has been asked before, I did try disable instant run. That is not working.

Let me explain in detail. I did this project on desktop, it is running fine. Now i need to migrate the code into my laptop, the code able to compile and generate an apk. When installing into my device xiaomi mi4 , it failed with DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR even if i manually transfer the apk file into the device and install it (that only tell me fail to install, i do not know how to know the reason of failure.  I am sure this is not the device problem since i am able to install the same source apk file (if i compile it on my desktop)

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the old version of the application on your device manually. Go to **Settings -> Apps** find your application there and delete it.
I think it may help.
If not check free memory on the device.

Comment: i am able to install the apk if i compile it on desktop. Same code, same device, even without delete my old app, it will auto delete and reinstall.

Comment: Yes, but sometimes it doesn't auto-deletes. So you need to delete it manually.

Comment: Try to disable instant run 
Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run

Comment: yes, i have done that before i asked here, and it was stated on top of the question.

Comment: Please, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34381853/failure-install-failed-update-incompatible-followed-by-delete-failed-internal). Maybe it will help you

Answer (score -1):

Go into your directory project and delete all the 'build' directories and the '.gradle' directory.

Answer (score -1):

if you use your android phone,

Developer options > Install via USB #Enable