# Why can't I simply copy source files and recompile on different PC?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have recently bought a new PC and setup Android Studio 1.5.1 on it. I copied source project folder from AndroidProjects folder on old PC to a new one on new PC.

I was able to open the project and **succesfully compile and run in emulator**. However when I connected my Galaxy S6 and tried to debug in it, it first complained about old version of app being installed (from old PC), and asked if I wish to uninstall. I said yes and since then I always get the folowing error:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER]
```

I am not asking how to resolve this issue (altho help would be appreciated), rather I am asking what is different on my new PC that makes compiled app incompatible in some way with old one? Nothing in source is changed, I do not sign my APK with any key now.

I need to know in order to avoid issues in future, when app is released and I need to change PC again.

Thanks!

Comment: Because, 2 computer of you have different debug keystore. So, you can't install same app with 2 key in your device. Do fix it, copy debug keystore from old computer and replace in new computer

Comment: The debug keystore is different on each machine, which probably caused your first issue.  As for `INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER `, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267785/install-shows-error-in-console-install-failed-conflicting-provider

Comment: I cannot confirm the solution by copying debug keystore file, as I may have found a Galaxy S6 bug. After first uninstall, package is no longer listed under installed apps, cannot list it even thru adb, cannot find its directories on phone and yet any attempt to uninstall results in DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR. I think I will factory reset my device. Btw, where to find debug keystore options in Android Studio? I found the file, but not in the AS settings. Thanks