# Some users are unable to install app from playstore. Error : Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER]

Tags: android

Some users are unable to install app from playstore. They get these errors:

1. Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER].
2. 505 : Duplicate Provider Authority.

Also Tried to install the app on those phones through ADB as per this [tutorial](https://ohthehugemanatee.org/blog/2015/05/29/troubleshooting-android-error-505-from-google-play/)
But it gave the following Error output with no description of the error.
c:\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb install D:\androidProjects\29febsecondhalf\app\app-release.apk
6568 KB/s (16204430 bytes in 2.409s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/app-release.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER]

These phones had already installed the previous version of the app earlier. But the new version gives this error. The previous version of app is not present in these phones now . (Also checked it through adb using adb uninstall Package_Name)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install shows error in console: INSTALL FAILED CONFLICTING PROVIDER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267785/install-shows-error-in-console-install-failed-conflicting-provider)

Answer (score 0):

Change your provider `android:authorities` it may be possible that same provider already defined (Duplicated).

> To avoid conflicts, authority names should use a Java-style naming
>   convention (such as com.example.provider.abcprovider). Typically,
>   it's the name of the ContentProvider 
>   subclass that implements the provider

**[For more detail visit developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html#auth)**

Comment: Currently there are two Content Providers:  1. <provider
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1234"
            android:exported="true" />
 and  2. <provider
            android:name=".map.provider.PlaceProvider"
            android:authorities="com.miamia.miamia.map.provider.PlaceProvider"
            android:exported="false" />