# How to fix 'Session 'app': Install failed.'

Tags: android

I was making a simple app with some text and images and i just added more codes like 'TextView', then 'Session 'app': Install failed.' keeps happening...

I have already turned off 'instant run' according to the solution here which didnt work. Buttons likes 'Clean Project','Rebuild Project' dont work.
Anybody like an engel has a solution for this ?

Comment: Are you using emulator or real device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with Invalid caches and restart

```
File > invalidate caches/restart > invalidate and restart
```

Comment: Thanks for the first and quick answer but i still get this error.                    
Session 'app': Install failed.Installation failed.Rerun

Comment: check this may be some of solution will work for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37015030/session-app-error-installing-apk/42617142

Comment: i just changed the type of phone in AVD and it worked. it was because of low spec of the phone in AVD i chose.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of the android studio try clicking on sync project with gradle files.

If this doesn't help try these solutions:-

1) Maybe your phone has low memory.

2) Try disabling instant run from:-
   File >Settings >Build,Execution,Deployment > Instant Run

3) Open gradle window from right side of android studio and hit refresh.

4) If you open the Event Log window in the right bottom corner of Android Studio, you can see a detailed error message.

I hope this helps.Please upvote if you find it helpful.Thanks

Comment: i just changed the type of phone in AVD and it worked. it was because of low spec of the phone in AVD i chose. Thanks

Comment: ok.no problem.please feel free to upvote the answer if it helped.thanks