# don't build and run my application in real hardware

Tags: android-studio

i try run my application on real hardware 
but  android studio return follow error

```
07:25 PM    'cmd package install-create -r -t -S 1676395' returns error 'Unknown failure: Exception occurred while executing:
                    android.os.ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space
                    at android.util.ExceptionUtils.wrap(ExceptionUtils.java:34)
                    at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSession(PackageInstallerService.java:596)
                    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.doCreateSession(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:1362)
                    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstallCreate(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:282)
                    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:118)
                    at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:96)
                    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:23614)
                    at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:574)
                    at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:474)
                    at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager... (show balloon)

07:26 PM    Session 'app': Error Installing APKs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happens because of many things

- First, Try Build -> Clean project then Build -> Rebuild project
- Get some free storage in your phone
- Disable instant-run
- make sure that usb-debugging is enabled

See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37015030/session-app-error-installing-apk), it may help.