# fail to install app on my device receiving INSTAL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER

Tags: android, build, android-contentprovider

When I am trying to build my app using android studio, I have faced with following error :

[image]

After clicking ok, it can not unistall the app because I already unistalled it. I get the following error :

$ adb shell pm uninstall com.siritime
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
Error while Installing APK

I was able run the app on my device before, a few  days ago I have added push notification ability using GCM and I am not sure if the problem is related to that (I add GCM codes to my project and customized it) . the app could run on similature or other devices well but not on my device,

Could u please guide me what is wrong on my phone ?
I have test some other solution in different  pages but they did not worked for me>> like [this one...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267785/install-shows-error-in-console-install-failed-conflicting-provider)

I did not used a provider, should I implement one ?

the part of manifest that I added from GCM push notification sample code is :`
        
            
                
                />

```
    <service
        android:name=".peyv.gcm.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>


    <service
        android:name=".peyv.gcm.MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".peyv.gcm.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false"></service>
```

`

thanks all

Comment: can u check in that device app list can u see your app.? If yes then do uninstall for all users.

Comment: you mean uninstall the app on mobile device ? I already did that, the app is not  exist on the mobile apps list

Comment: okay then can u post ur manifest?

Comment: The app manifest is about 360 lines, do you have any suggestion ? what do u want to see ? the app can run on the emulator and there is no problem with that, should I post it here ?

Comment: okay post the <receiver/> Tag which has android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"

Comment: <!-- Needed for push notification -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111435/discussion-between-sirvan-paraste-and-raghavendra).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear all I have found the problem myself, so I don't know if somebody else will face to this or not, just I share mine solution and hope it help someone:

I add an applicationID to my gradel like this

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "App Package Name like com.example"
    multiDexEnabled true
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
}
```

Thanks all.