# How to install multiple product flavours on a device avoiding code -505 for Android

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

Hello and thanks for your intertest :)

I have an app that has many 'flavors', and would like them installed side by side on the same device. the flavors each have their own icons and name (applicationId) , so I'm not sure why it says they are conflicting

The build.gradle looks something like this:

```
productFlavors {
    flavaflave1 {
        applicationId "com.company.appname.flavor1"
        resValue "string", "APP_PACKAGE", applicationId
        versionCode 18
        versionName "3.0.0"
    }
    flavaflave2 {
        applicationId "com.company.appname.flavor2"
        resValue "string", "APP_PACKAGE", applicationId
        versionCode 25
        versionName "4.2.0"
    }
```

}

When i install via Android studio i get "INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER", or from google play it throw -505. Is this possible? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Judging from this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267785/install-shows-error-in-console-install-failed-conflicting-provider) `android:authorities` in your manifest must be different as well?

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what i will need!