# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER]

Tags: android

I have checked all possible answers on this question here, but none has helped me. I don't know what to do anymore. I have already uninstalled application on mobile phone, and it is still saying me this:

[image]

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:name="com.solaris.timster.app.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name="com.solaris.timster.activities.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.solaris.timster.activities.WelcomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.solaris.timster.activities.LogRegActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.solaris.timster.activities.GuideStepper"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.solaris.timster.activities.HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.solaris.timster.activities.CreateTeamActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

    <!-- Firebase Notifications -->
    <service android:name="com.solaris.timster.gcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name="com.solaris.timster.gcm.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- ./Firebase Notifications -->
</application>
```

and my build.gradle app file:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.solaris.timster"
}
```

Comment: A `<provider>` element is being added to your manifest by a library. Some other application on your device has a `<provider>` element with the same `android:authorities` value.

Comment: Try changing your applicationId (application android:name).

Comment: @CommonsWare you were right. It was some library, which was messing things arroung. Thanks for pointing me out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267785/install-shows-error-in-console-install-failed-conflicting-provider

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install shows error in console: INSTALL FAILED CONFLICTING PROVIDER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267785/install-shows-error-in-console-install-failed-conflicting-provider)