# App install failed (INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER)

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, failed-installation

I had an old project, but I wanted to rename it, so I made a duplicate of the old project then renamed the new project's gradle applicationId and created a new signing file for it. But now why can't the new project and the old project be installed on the same device together?

Error:

[image]

Comment: what's more,i have tried to close the instant run,but it still not work .

Comment: Have you tried changing package name from the manifest?

Comment: yes,i changed it before,but it doesn't work..

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that you are using the same provider name/id in two different apps.
See [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267785/install-shows-error-in-console-install-failed-conflicting-provider)

Basically make sure your provider ids are based on the app id.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions,it works .I modified the new  provider 's authorities into "timeory_com.pgyersdk.provider",the old is "com.pgyersdk.provider"

Answer (score 0):

Check your package name in build.gradle and in your manifest.. and check if you are using something like facebook or anything that is connected to your old project or package name.

Comment: thanks for your response,i checked that again,but there's  nothing wrong