# Changing Android Package Name - UAMP

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

I am using the UAMP-Example provided by Android on GitHub.

The Uamp-Project has been optimized by myself and now i would like to change the com.example.android.uamp (and all corresponding files for Android Auto too) to my custom ch.test.appname.

I tried to change soo many files but got dozens of 'file not found' Errors.

Which files to i have to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make use of the built in Rename functionality of Android Studio to rename your package. First change your project scope from **Android** to **Project**:

[image]

Then navigate into the **java** folder and select your package (e.g. `com.example.test`)

**Right click** -> **Refactor** -> **Rename**

Click **Rename Package**

Type in your new package name and all dependencies should update automatically.

Answer (score 0):

To change your package name follow the below steps:
First click below mark icon -> [image]

Then You see a window like below and click the mark selection area -> [image]

Then you will see your package name is divided by part wise like com/nayan/myapp
like below image -> [image]

Then click the Right button on any part which you want to change The Select `Refactor -> Rename` and then click `Package name`. Change your package name and click ok.

After that you should change your package name manually from your `build.gradle(Module)` Also check your `manifest file` if the manifest package name is not changed change it manually. That's it.

Comment: Thats done, but i got the Following Error: `INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER`. You know what that means?

Comment: Hope this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267785/install-shows-error-in-console-install-failed-conflicting-provider

Answer (score 0):

Using Nayan Sarder's answer solved my Problem. But i had to open the whole project in VisualStudio-Code and had to change com.example.abc.appname... to ch.example.abc.appname manually.

Thank's Nayan!